# WiFi local storage file access/sharing via web browser is possible with window phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to know that I creates files (lets say simple .txt-files) and saves them to its own local storage. The phone is connected to a local network using WiFi. A PC (doesn't matter what platform) is connected to the same network and is getting access to the apps own local storage (and the files). Read-only would be enough.

Is this possible with WP8 or is there a VERY SIMILAR solution available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible if your app is running at the moment when PC wants to get the access. Then there are different options on how to do that (creating local TCP server and then implementing some simple protocol for file transfer on both phone and PC). But it can be much easier if your app just sends files via HTTP to web server running on your PC.

If you want to access isolated storage from something else than the app which owns that storage, as you described it, then forget it, no way.

---

Okay, if you want the file transfer during application execution, that's definitely possible. I would only advise you to run a HTTP *server* on the **PC** and HTTP *client* in your app on the **phone**. Doing it other way (server on phone, client on PC) would be much more difficult. This also means that it is your phone will have to initiate the transfer, not the PC.

If it's okay for you, install some web server on your PC (like Apache). Configuration of it is definitely out of scope of this question. Regarding the Windows Phone, take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221581.aspx) on how to do HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to transfer file from Phone local storage to PC or get file from PC to Local storage via wifi is there any possibility ?

Comment: That is what Haspemulator explained. Your app is the only thing that has access. Therefore, your app needs to be running and can simply send the files to a server running on your PC. Are you perhaps asking about a library/protocol for file transfer that you could use? You might need to edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: Guessing from the title -- are you asking about implementing a web server in your phone app such that users can download files from your phone app using a desktop browser?

Comment: Yes, i am asking about implementing a web server in my phone app that users can download files from my phone app using a desktop browser... is it possible ? if yes than please tell me how and also tell me library/protocol for file transfering.

Comment: i want to implement a web server in my phone app that users can download files from my phone app or upload form a desktop browser in windows phone 8... is it possible ??